How to fit width of select option with form-select in Bootstrap 5.3.3?
I see that in older Bootstrap version you could use data-width=fit to set the width of the selectpicker follow the width of the values. Now in Bootstrap 5.3.3. I use the form-select with several option values of various sizes. The arrow down of the dropdown menu positions itself on the right side of the longest option value. I am using this form-select in a menubar for selecting the language and this looks rather ugly when the shorter value is selected. I have been tryin all day to find a solution but cannot seem to find anything. Anybody any idea? Here is the code of the menu:
<div class="dropdown">
     <select id="language-select" class="form-select border-0 bg-transparent" aria-label="Default select">
           <option value="index.php">English</option>
           <option value="index_NL.php">Nederlands</option>
           <option value="index_DE.php">Deutsch</option>
           <option value="index_IT.php">Italiano</option>
      </select>
</div>

Bootstrap 5 positions the arrow down through the background-position: right ..rem center;
I figured that out but I really can't think of a way to make that flexible.
Thanks for ur help!
I tried javascript, calculating the width size of the option value and adding a padding to that, but I keep getting funny inconsistent results

Use Bootstrap classes to size controls
A select and a dropdown are separate components. The code incorrectly inserts a select inside of a dropdown. This creates conflicts with both layout and events.
To fix the problem, make the language control either a select or a dropdown. A dropdown automatically sizes to fit the text. However, a select will expand to 100% width when the form-select class is applied. To make the select auto size, use an inline form or alternatively add the w-auto class.
The code snippet shows how to creates both a select and a dropdown with a checkmark ✓ on the selected item.



// select

const langSelect = document.getElementById('lang-select');

langSelect.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  console.log(langSelect.value);
})

// dropdown 

const langDropdown = document.getElementById('lang-dropdown')

langDropdown.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('dropdown-item')) {
  
    let selected = event.target;
    let value = selected.getAttribute('href');

    // add checkmark to selected lang
    langDropdown.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item').forEach(item => {
      item.classList.toggle('checked', item === selected)
    })
     
    // sync value with other control 
    langSelect.value = value; 
    console.log(value);
  }
})
.dropdown-item.checked::after {
  content: "\2713";
  float: right;
}
<div class="container p-2">

  <strong>Select:</strong>
  <select id="lang-select" class="form-select m-1 w-auto" aria-label="Default select">
    <option value="#index.php">English</option>
    <option value="#index_NL.php">Nederlands</option>
    <option value="#index_DE.php">Deutsch</option>
    <option value="#index_IT.php">Italiano</option>
  </select>

  <strong>Dropdown:</strong>
  <div class="dropdown m-1" id="lang-dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Language
  </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item checked" href="#index.php">English</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#index_NL.php">Nederlands</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#index_DE.php">Deutsch</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#index_IT.php">Italiano</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>




Thanks for answering! Unfortunately I get the same behviour with ur select option. Both in your code snippet and on my website. the width doesn’t change with the option value chosen. So when English is chosen, I see ‘English’ a lot of space and then the dropdown arrow. The width is still set by the value ‘Nederlands’. And the dropdown also doesn't work: the selected language doesn't show in the dropdown box so I cannot see it it works. Als the check V has some funny behaviour.  Perhaps I am doing something wrong.
